# Print output as it goes with Process

Tags: c#, .net, process

I found some code like this. It runs a process then prints what it wrote to standard output. The problem is, that it doesn't print *anything* until the process has exited which might take a very long time (or not at all). Thus, I'd rather print the output AS IT GOES. How can I do that?

```
var startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd", "/c sleepy.bat")
    {RedirectStandardOutput = true, UseShellExecute = false, CreateNoWindow = true };
var p = new Process(){StartInfo = startInfo};
p.Start();
string output = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
Console.WriteLine(output);
```

Where `sleepy.bat` could be

```
echo "About to execute really slow query.."
sleep 20
echo "Finished!"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `p.StandardOutput.BeginOutputReadLine()`. You will receive output as it goes from the process in `OutputDataReceived` event.

For extended example, take a look at [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.outputdatareceived.aspx).